# C++ template trait to specify any unsigned integral type

Tags: c++, templates, traits, unsigned-integer

I’m trying to implement a function which accepts only unsigned integral types.  Below is what I’ve tried so far. It works for "unsigned int", but why doesn’t this compile for an "unsigned short?"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
inline const T oddProduct(T n) noexcept {
    return (n <= 1) ? n : (n % 2) ? oddProduct(n - 2)*n : oddProduct(--n);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Product of odd integers from 1 to 15: " << oddProduct<unsigned short>(15) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: MSVS 2017 Community C++14 options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that due to the [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

```
n - 2
```

has a type of `int` which is not `unsigned`.

You might try to add `static_cast`:

```
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
inline const T oddProduct(T n) noexcept {
    return (n <= 1) ? n : (n % 2) ? oddProduct(static_cast<T>(n - 2))*n : oddProduct(--n);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

so `n - 2` is casted to `unsigned short` when you call `oddProduct<unsigned short>`.

Another possible option is to change `2` to `2U`.

---

Also note, that, once you use *C++14*, you might use `std::enable_if_t`:

```
class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/3aBWPZ)

Comment: Also note that since C++17, you can replace `std::is_unsigned<T>::value` with `std::is_unsigned_v<T>`.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont yup, but OP has explicitly specified *C++14*

Answer (score 0):

[Edgar Rokyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389005/4944425)'s answer addresses the integral promotion issue in OP's code, but there is another problem reguarding the return value type and the possible overflow of the calculations.

As a matter of fact, considering the example provided in the question, the *"product of odd integers from 1 to 15"* is 2027025, a value that requires more then 16 bits (the size of an `unsigned short` in most systems), so that letting the function return the same type of its parameter would lead to wrong results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
inline const auto oddProduct(T n)  noexcept 
-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, unsigned long long> {
    return n < T{2}
        ? n
        : (n % T{2})
            ? oddProduct<T>(n - T{2})*n
            : oddProduct(--n);
}

template<typename T>
inline const auto oddProduct(T n) 
-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value, unsigned long long> {
    if ( n < 0 ) throw std::domain_error("Negative value passed");
    return n < T{2}
        ? n
        : (n % T{2})
            ? oddProduct<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(n - T{2})*n
            : oddProduct<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(--n);
}

int main() {
    unsigned char n0 {15};
    std::cout << "Product of odd integers from 1 to 15: " << oddProduct(n0) << '\n';
    unsigned short n1 {15};
    std::cout << "Product of odd integers from 1 to 15: " << oddProduct(n1) << '\n';
    unsigned n2 {15};
    std::cout << "Product of odd integers from 1 to 15: " << oddProduct(n2) << '\n';
    short n3 {15};
    std::cout << "Product of odd integers from 1 to 15: " << oddProduct(n3) << '\n';  
}
```

In my proposal, the function always returns an `unsigned long long`. I also added an overload to deal with signed types.